# Recursively list all potential types of specific property

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a complex hierarchical tree structure of many different classes. Each node is called a `Symbol` which has a property called `parent`. I was wanting to make a function that returns the list of all the parents down the hiararchy tree. Which may be off different types but all end in `BookClass` which is the prime root node of the tree.

```js
class Sentence extends Symbol {
    parent : Paragraph
}

class Paragraph extends Symbol {
    parent : Section
}

class Section extends Symbol {
    parent : BookClass | Section | Chapter
}

class Chapter extends Symbol {
    parent : BookClass
}

// The goal here is to return the list of the possible parents
// that could arise given that the argument type is known.
// EG, passing a paragraph would limit the return value to
// (Symbol & (BookClass | Section | Chapter))[]

function getParentList<T extends Symbol>(object : T) : Parentize<T> {
    const list : Parentize<T>[] = [] // <-- Parentize is the question here
    list.push(object)
    let parent : T | Symbol | BookClass
    // While there is a parent and that parent is not BookClass
    while ((parent = object.parent) && !(parent instanceof BookClass)) {
        list.push(parent)
        object = parent
    }
    return list
}
```

This would allow a greater accuracy of return values given what I pass in, which would help in different parts of the code.

Here's what I had in mind for the `Parentize` - it doesn't work obviously - but I don't know how to write this one:

```
type Parentize<T extends Symbol> = T['parent'] | T['parent']['parent'] | T['parent']['parent']['parent']... etc until BookClass
```

There's a small issue which is that sometimes the parents can be recursive. For example sometimes sections have subsections. IE the parent type of `Section` is `Section | Chapter | BookClass` which might create an infinite loop.

Please illuminate my mind!

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example. How is `Symbol` defined or `BookClass`? Are you aware that the name `Symbol` collides with the existing [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol?retiredLocale=de) constructor?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mMBrbW) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer explaining. Otherwise, what am I missing? (Pls ping me via @jcalz if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz Yes! That looks like it does what's desired. Would you mind explaining how it works?

Comment: I will do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a first-draft implementation of `Parentize<T>`:

```
type Parentize1<T> = T extends { parent: infer V } ? V | Parentize1<V> : never;
```

This is a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) that checks if `T` has a `parent` property, and if so, you get the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the `parent` property type with `Parentize<>` on the parent.  This is conceptually the same as `T["parent"] | T["parent"]["parent"] | T["parent"]["parent"]["parent"] | ...`, where we only stop when we reach some type that doesn't have a `parent` property.

We can test it on a made-up example:

```
interface Foo { parent: Bar };
interface Bar { parent: Baz };
interface Baz { }
type P = Parentize1<Foo>; // type P = Bar | Baz
```

And that works well.

But your "small" issue with circular data types turns into a rather big issue in the definition, which would keep recursing into the parent properties without end:

```
type Oops = Parentize1<Section>; // error!
// Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
```

So we need to change the implementation to avoid infinite regress.

---

One approach is to give `Parentize<T>` a second type argument `U` corresponding to the union of types it has already seen, and then before evaluating `Parentize<T>`, we remove anything from `T` that has already been seen (which can be written as `Exclude<T, U>` using [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion)).  Like this:

```
type Parentize<T, U = never> =
  Exclude<T, U> extends { parent: infer V } ? V | Parentize<V, T | U> : never;
```

You can see that in the recursive call to `Parentize`, we add `T` to the list of things we've seen before (we pass `T | U` instead of just `U`).  So that should prevent us from getting stuck in a loop.  When you call `Parentize<T>`, `U` starts off as `never` because we haven't seen any other types yet.  If `T["parent"]` is `V`, then we return `V | Parentize<V, T>`.

Let's try it.  For non-recursive types nothing changes:

```
type P2 = Parentize<Foo> // type P2 = Bar | Baz;
```

But for recursive types we now get the answer you want without a compiler error:

```
type Okay = Parentize<Section>; // okay
  // type Okay = Bookinterface | Section | Chapter
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DK6C2AjAewBtkBvZAXwChRJZEUAhAgga1uniWQgA9IQAEwDOaLLkIly1DvW6YI4Rdz4CRY7PmJkqyZAAc4URWABcyAApG4Acyhx9ACyoylclFft2Hjnv0XqGJqSOnqGxuDmCghgwAQgLjRuXCjRsfF+aqJBEtqkugZGJubMbLIpyAA+yGlxIFXIAMKODnSJ5QxNLfp0mQHZ4lpSBeHFyKXsyQyJSXQVAGIsZIURZuNGlADcs5ydjBvko5HrAF5bO+6ny9RUYOj6HkXgwCcQAIwAPAAqAHzIALzIL59ISiQ5PNagGDQZAANUoyAA-HCGp4TC93h9YX9zCAIAA3aDbO4PSwAywQjGfRYEH6bZAAegZyBJHnJ+ygDX2J1u9xQAHkCPpRIC0c9Xp9avE6YzmdAoAQoABCKhMoF85CgYRgODPODperAUR8JDCYTAQlEdDIQQQCD6ZC6wQGAhm4B4K2akAwUDASAAOiovNJYtir2+ABpkABVcl4wlQP7-AoAUV4CCIAFdbZGY39VP1lkdId6YfCKEiUdVQxisVHgdVozjkPGiUHWZYAEzkmvhml-NUdizdwEcrlwE7EjX81hwa2iynhqUgH6q5kdmdz9ksSZzTrVZcNZqtaBBoNAA)